# Publish WebApi to Azure when update to .Net 5.0 from .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net, azure, migration

I have stumbled upon a problem today. I have changed the

```
<TargetFramework>netcore3.1</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

And my working Azure Pipeline got broken, but with no visible error.
It built and it Relesased to App Service, but the API was returning 404.

As I searched Stack and Net I have not found similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that some people are Publishing from within Visual Studio with Self-contained option.
I did not get it but tried and it worked!
So I changed one line in my Azure Pipeline in dotnet publish section:

```
-c Release -o out -r linux-x64
```

to

```
-c Release -o out -r linux-x64 --self-contained true
```

And it helped!

I have no idea why, as from MS docs it seems it should be the defualt if you are using -r option
it is self contained by default. But if somebody will have similar problem I hope it will help!

Cheers!
Piotr